# "wrong final block length" when Ruby decrypts data encrypted by go

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, go

I'm trying to encrypt a piece of data in Go and then store it into a database to be later pulled out and decrypted by Rails.

Here is the Go encryption code:

```
func Encrypt(text []byte) ([]byte, error) {
  key := []byte("a very very very very secret key")
  block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)

  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  b := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(text)
  ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(b))
  iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]

  if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  cfb := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
  cfb.XORKeyStream(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], []byte(b))

  return ciphertext, nil
}
```

And here is my Ruby code to decrypt:

```
def decrypt(message)
  key = "a very very very very secret key"

  iv = message[0, 14]
  data = message[15, message.length+1]

  key = Digest::SHA256.digest(key) if(key.kind_of?(String) && 32 != key.bytesize)
  iv = Digest::MD5.digest(iv) if(iv.kind_of?(String) && 16 != iv.bytesize)

  aes = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC')
  aes.decrypt
  aes.key = key
  aes.iv = iv
  aes.update(data) + aes.final
end
```

This is giving me an error message of:

```
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: wrong final block length
```

Can anyone help let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't encrypt using CFB, then decrypt using CBC. They are different modes of operation.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the ruby code to CFB worked, but now the output is coming in like "\xCE\x81\xD3\xB6\x15", how do I convert it to a normal string?

Comment: That should be asked in a new question, since it's a different problem.  In the new question, it's fair for the new and old questions to include links to each other.

Comment: Ok, I'll put it in a new question, thanks